# Why ' ' was used in select statement

Tags: mysql, select

Came across this code today:

```
SELECT 'Overall' as Main,
        wave,
        country,
        catg,
        '' AS hw,
        SUM(0) AS headwinds_sum
....
....
```

Can someone explain what ' ' in the above stands for?
Its not a typo as it is repeated @multiple instances.

Not a typo, no text was missed to add.

Comment: Can you share the full query? I'm guessing there's a `union` or `union all` hiding somewhere there

Comment: Its an empty string. This will return a column with the name hw which value is an empty string. As Mureiknik already mentioned, revealing the whole statement migth give a hint why an empty string is returned.

Comment: Side note: it's never a good thing to have empty strings to represent missing values. They should be represented with the NULL value, which is better handled by any DBMS.

Comment: Yes, there is a union all right below it in the next statement. I pasted only the part which was blocking me. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'' as hw
```

adds a column named `hw` to your select query of type `varchar` that contains empty strings.

Depending on how you process the resultset afterwards this can make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is used to return an empty column in a result set. Users occasionally do this to match column counts in insert selects or when exporting data to Excel files and you want standard column names for capturing audit recommendations on data etc.

Comment: I got the explanation expected. thanks for the quick update